# Receiving Permission denied when trying to use cat command to create a file

Tags: cat

I am working with Ubuntu version 18.04.4 LTS.  I tried to create a file using the following command:  sudo cat > filename.yaml and received a "Permission denied error"  I can create the file using the VIM editor and sudo.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on `cat` but I suspect the command as you've entered it above will produce an error by design.  Cat is used to print and concatenate files.

Example commands with `cat` are `cat filename.yaml` which will  print the contents of *filename.yaml* to standard output (i.e. the terminal); while `cat file1.yaml file2.yaml > filename.yaml` will combine the contents of the existing files *file1.yaml* and *file2.yaml* into a new file called *filename.yaml*.

Comment: Aside from the "permission denied" error (which is from the *shell*, not from `cat`, and reflects the user's lack of rights in the target directory), the command `cat > filename` will indeed create `filename` - however, it will hang waiting to read file contents from standard input. Simply hitting Ctrl-D will terminate the command, resulting in creation of an empty file, similar to `touch filename` or `> filename`

Comment: A good point, thank you; I've learnt something.  As Ctrl-D means EOF it makes sense that this termination would result in an empty file.  However having said that `cat` still probably won't be the first tool out of the box next time I want to create an empty file ;)